# Fetch resource manually [GraphQL]

Tags: reactjs, graphql, admin-on-rest

Can you tell me what would be the best way to get a resource manually in custom component?
I'm using the simple GraphQL client for admin-on-rest.

Comment: Can you precise the exact package you are using ? `aor-simple-graphql-client` has been deprecated. Also, please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: yes, I was using the `aor-simple-graphql-client`, I'll try to change to migrate to `aor-graphql` which as I see is the new one.
The thing that I want to do is to have buttons which on click to fetch data from different GraphQL endpoints and pass them to List component.

Comment: For custom fetches, you should use your own ApolloClient and make your requests by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aor-simple-graphql-client` has been deprecated. Note that `aor-graphql-client` is meant to be used for admin-on-rest requests. If you need to send your own queries, you should use a custom ApolloClient and follow their documentation